# Using rsync to merge two source directories

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive, rsync

I have my photos on an external disk, which I back up to my server by manually running a script that uses rsync. This script ensures that my external disk and my backup are in sync, which means copying any new photos and deleting any photos that were deleted from the external disk.

I use the following command to achieve this:

```
rsync -av --exclude '.*' --delete $SRC/ $HOST:/path/to/backup
```

This has worked fine for years. However, I've run out of disk space on the external disk now, so I bought another one. I'm planning to keep the same directory structure on the new disk, as I have on the old one, e.g.:

```
Events/
    2023-05 Event1/
    2023-07 Event2/
Travel/
    2023-06 Trip1/
    2023-07 Trip2/
```

##### Question:

Can I somehow modify my rsync backup script to merge both my external disks into a single backup folder on my server?

##### Example:

I have two source directories with a similar structure:

```
Source1/
    A/
        1/
        2/
        3/
    B/
        10/
        20/

Source2/
    A/
        4/
        5/
    B/
        30/
```

And I want my destination to contain files and directories from both, using the same directory structure:

```
Destination/
    A/
        1/
        2/
        3/
        4/
        5/
    B/
        10/
        20/
        30/
```

Can I somehow achieve this, while still making sure that files that have been deleted from the source directories also get cleaned up from the destination directory (using the --delete flag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to keep the old drive as an "active" source which you will keep deleting and adding stuff from, and that you *absolutely* want to merge both drives in the same directory ?

I don't think this is possible with a rsync one-liner, AFAIK rsync only deals with a single source; it cannot know if a folder present in the destination is a deleted folder from one source (which should be deleted) or an existing folder in the other (which should be kept), and by default will delete everything from the drive you're not syncing.

If we're willing to make it a (small) script: you can build a list of the files on source B, then use it as an exclusion list in rsync when you sync source A, and vice-versa, and keep using the same rsync call except for that extra exclusion list. This should make it so that rsync does not delete files from the other disk, but does delete stuff that isn't on any drive. However, it will overwrite files with the same path with whichever drive was synced last.

We'd end up with something like this (this is ***untested***, correction and testing is left to the reader, try it on sample data, etc)

```bash
find ${drive_A_syncroot}/* | xargs realpath --relative-to=${drive_A_syncroot} > exclusion-list-A.csv
find ${drive_B_syncroot}/* | xargs realpath --relative-to=${drive_B_syncroot} > exclusion-list-B.csv
rsync -av --exclude '.*' --exclude-from=exclusion-list-B.csv --delete ${drive_A_syncroot}/ $HOST:/path/to/backup
rsync -av --exclude '.*' --exclude-from=exclusion-list-A.csv --delete ${drive_B_syncroot}/ $HOST:/path/to/backup
```

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks! I will try it out soon and mark your answer if it works. I didn't know that an exclusion list also prevents destination files from being deleted - I thought it just prevents source files from being copied. And yes, your assumptions are correct: I want to keep using the first disk as an active source, and I do want to merge them into a single directory. There is also no risk of having the same file paths on both disks.

Comment: That worked, thanks! For completeness, here's my full script: https://github.com/jmerhar/photography/blob/main/photo-backup.sh